# Common code handling in angular2 like angular1

Tags: angular

**Angular1**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <ui-view>
           
      <ui-view>
</div>
```

Here different views will be injected in `ui-view`.
Let's say **home.html** is injected so **homeCtrl** will come into pic.

I can consider  **AppCtrl** is parent when **homeCtrl** is child.

Moreover when **homeCtrl** is initialized, **AppCtrl** is also called once as Parent/Child scenario.

So throughout application I can put ***common code*** in **AppCtrl**

**Angular2**

Boot.ts  <===== shouldn't constructor be called everytime? *[This is just my thought]* 
|_____Home.ts
|_____Aboutus.ts

**Boot.ts**

```
export class BootCmp{
  constructor(){
     console.log('Should this run everytime??')
  }
}
```

**Which is best way to put common code?

sharedService? 

Or some other mechanism is there?**

Comment: I guess you forgot the `constructor() { console.log(...) }` in `BootCmp`? "Let's say home.html is injected so homeCtrl" HTML isn't injected. What is "home.html" and "homeCtrl"?

Comment: I meant when you target `homeCtrl` by targeting `home.html`, in angular1 `parent` controller is also initialized or called. So I'm looking for such kinda architecture where `parent` is called everytime. If your background is `.net`, you must be knowing that parent form is always called.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand a single word. Hopefully @Sasxa s answer is helpful for you.

Comment: No problem. If you forget about @Input and @Output how would you achieve communication between components (parent/child) without using `sharedService` Probably these are the ways to make communication. May be, my question belongs to old technology's design pattern. `Angular2` has come up with `@Input` and `@Output` hook but consider how things would be without such things! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Root component of your app is "constructed" once - `constructor()` is called when you bootstrap the application. The rest of the components are created and destroyed based on your app logic, for example using router or `ngIf`.

Not sure what you consider "common code" but you can plan with this in mind...

Answer (score 0):

What i read in your question and your comments are two concerns:
One is Compoment Communication and the other is CommonCode-Initialsation.

1. Component Communication:

If you "forget" @Input and @Output, it is possible to use a service for communication between parent and child.

See the MissionControlExample in the Angular 2 cookbook for example:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

If you don´t want to use a shared service, use EventEmitter for Example.
See: Parent listens for child event (same link as MissionControlExample)

One of the advantages of Angular 2 is the suport of the HTLM5 webcomponent concept, so .html is a part of a component as template element.

2. CommonCode Initialisation
   Depends on the CommonCode. If it is App specific, initialse it in your AppComponent, if it is Component specific inialise it in the Component.
   It depends... on your code.

To answer more concrete, please share your code in your question.